# Unable to insert to hive partitioned table from spark sql

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, hive

I am having a hive partitioned table txnaggr_rt_fact and it has 2 column partitions
txninterval and intervaltype. I am trying to insert a record to this table from spark sql using java. During insert the throws an exception. If the partition doesn't exist as it has to create a new one and fails doing so but If the partition is already existing the record is getting inserted.

Java code is as follows

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
          .builder()
          .appName("Java Spark Hive Example")
          .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "hdfs://localhost:8020/user/hive/warehouse")
          .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
          .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
          .enableHiveSupport()
          .getOrCreate();

        spark.sql("show databases").show();
        spark.sql("use nadb");
       /* spark.sql("hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true");
        spark.sql("set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict");*/
        spark.sql("insert into table txnaggr_rt_fact partition (txninterval = '2017-01-11', intervaltype='Test') values('"+21+"',null,'"+22+"',"+23+")");
```

The exception when I am inserting to hive partitioned table is as follows

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.NullPointerException: null;
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:106)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.loadPartition(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:843)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.processInsert(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:249)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.run(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:115)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:190)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:190)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3253)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3252)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:190)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:638)
        at com.cw.na.spark.HiveSqlTest.main(HiveSqlTest.java:76)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:879)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:197)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:227)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.replaceFiles(Hive.java:3412)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.loadPartition(Hive.java:1650)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.loadPartition(Hive.java:1579)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.Shim_v0_14.loadPartition(HiveShim.scala:836)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$loadPartition$1.apply$mcV$sp(HiveClientImpl.scala:741)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$loadPartition$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:739)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$loadPartition$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:739)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$withHiveState$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.liftedTree1$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.retryLocked(HiveClientImpl.scala:209)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.withHiveState(HiveClientImpl.scala:255)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.loadPartition(HiveClientImpl.scala:739)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$loadPartition$1.apply$mcV$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:855)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$loadPartition$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:843)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$loadPartition$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:843)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:97)
        ... 25 more
```

I found that in my hive-site.xml which is present in spark/conf directory the `hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode` was set to `strict`. I have changed it to `nonstrict` and even in code I have put the configurations for hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode and hive.exec.dynamic.partition even then I am getting the same exception.

`hive-site.xml`

```
  <property>
    <name>hive.exec.dynamic.partition</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>Whether or not to allow dynamic partitions in DML/DDL.</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode</name>
    <value>nonstrict</value>
    <description>
      In strict mode, the user must specify at least one static partition
      in case the user accidentally overwrites all partitions.
      In nonstrict mode all partitions are allowed to be dynamic.
    </description>
  </property>
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you instead

```
 spark.sql("insert into table txnaggr_rt_fact partition (txninterval = '2017-01-11', intervaltype='Test') values('"+21+"',null,'"+22+"',"+23+")");
```

try

```
 spark.sql("insert overwrite table txnaggr_rt_fact partition (txninterval, intervaltype) values('"+21+"',null,'"+22+"',"+23+",'2017-01-11','Test')");
```

Here is how I do insert:

```
sql("create table if not exists table_test (a int, b int) partitioned by (ds string)")
sql("set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict")
sql("insert overwrite table_test partition(ds) select a, b, '2017-01-01' from other_table")
```

Comment: I am getting the below Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.loadDynamicPartitions(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path, java.lang.String, java.util.Map, boolean, int, boolean, boolean, boolean, long)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)

Comment: I added to my answer above.

Comment: I don't want to overwrite the existing data of the table. I just want to append to hive table. In this case what should I do?

Comment: To don't overwrite just remove "overwrite" from the query. Also check DDL of your table like 'describe table' to check if you have both columns for your partitions. Then you can do just INSERT statement as above.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to create special table because it would be transactional, so by default its off.
example:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  id                int,
  name              string
)
CLUSTERED BY (id) INTO 2 BUCKETS STORED AS ORC
TBLPROPERTIES ("transactional"="true",
  "compactor.mapreduce.map.memory.mb"="2048",     -- specify compaction map job properties
  "compactorthreshold.hive.compactor.delta.num.threshold"="4",  -- trigger minor compaction if there are more than 4 delta directories
  "compactorthreshold.hive.compactor.delta.pct.threshold"="0.5" -- trigger major compaction if the ratio of size of delta files to
                                                               -- size of base files is greater than 50%
);
```

then execute some configs like this https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions
an huge issue is that you wouldnt inserto into external table that it has already created.